# Erlang: Returning a function from a function

Tags: erlang

I know Erlang supports anonymous functions. My question is, can I return a function from a function then call that returned function from outside? If so, how do I do it? I know this is possible in many languages such as C and Python. Here is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```
-module(test).
-export([run/0]).

test() ->
    io:format("toasters", []).

bagel() ->
    test.

run() ->
    (bagel())().
```

Results:

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c(test).
test.erl:4: Warning: function test/0 is unused
{ok,test}
2> test:run().
** exception error: bad function test
     in function  test:run/0 (test.erl, line 11)
3>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, here we go:

```
-module(test).
-export([run/0]).

test() ->
    io:format("toasters", []).

bagel() ->
    fun test/0. % <- This is what I needed to change.

run() ->
    (bagel())().
```

I was looking [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions) for an answer, and they didn't explicitly state it, but the example near the top gave me the hint just now.

Comment: This made me smile -- you found your own answer and you'll now never forget it. Just keep it clear in your mind that while a function *label* is an atom, a complete function identity is its label/parity.

Comment: @zxq9 I actually did forget it right after... but NOW I'll never forget! I forgot to put in the `fun` before my functions and was wondering why I was getting `badarith` errors; I was dividing an atom!